# Mingling switch and while in C

Tags: c, while-loop, switch-statement

This code works for some reason but it does not make sense at all.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  switch(1)
    {
      case 0:
        while(1)
          {
            case 1: puts("Works"); break;
          }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain why it does work and what applications does this have?

Comment: http://c-faq.com/misc/duff.html

Comment: @0A0D It's a different question!

Comment: @saadtaame: Looks the same to me. It's a Duff's device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can interleave statements through the labels of `switch`, since they're just labels. What happens here is:

- you have an infinite loop defined using `while (1)`;
- the `switch (1)` statement jumps to the `case 1:` label;
- where `"Works"` is printed, then `break;` exits the inifinite loop.

Answer (score 8):

The `case` labels are almost exactly like labels used by `goto`.<sup>1</sup>  If you think of your code in those terms, it should be clear that it's valid.  Namely, you can consider a `switch` statement to be a glorified conditional `goto`.

That said, I would slap anyone who wrote code like that in a production environment.<sup>2</sup>

---

1. In fact, they are both listed in the same grammar section (6.8.1) of the C99 standard.
2. Yes, this is almost identical to [Duff's device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device), but that last had any practical use decades ago.

Comment: A link to the standard if possible? (or the exact section :D)

Comment: @saadtaame: See the footnote in my answer!

Comment: I saw it in use in code that mimics exceptions in C.

Answer (score 5):

The reason this works is somewhat non-intuitive: `case` labels of a `switch` statement act very much like regular labels, i.e. the ones designed for use with `goto` statement. You can place such labels anywhere in your code.

It turns out that the same rule applies to the `case` label: you can place them anywhere inside their corresponding `switch` statement, which incidentally includes the bodies of any nested loops.

The reasons why you may *want* to place labels inside control statements within the body of your `switch` statement are even less intuitive: it turns out that you can perform loop unrolling with a cumbersome-looking but very intuitive construct called [*Duff's Device*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device). It is this construct that lead to popularizing the idea of embedding case labels inside other control structures within `switch` statements.

Comment: Thanks. What's loop unrolling? I'm interested

Comment: @saadtaame Loop unrolling (AKA "loop unwinding") is when you repeat the body of a loop several (say, four) times, and simultaneously decrease the number of times the loop executes. This does the same amount of work with less iteration, thus decreasing per-iteration costs (checking the exit condition and incrementing indexes). Here is [a link to a wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org)./wiki/Loop_unwinding